# Recover data from bak Oracle 9i file

Tags: oracle, rman

Our customer gave us a .bak archive with name file_decrypted_379299.bak which we know was created with Oracle 9i in "hot" style.

We tried to recover the bak file with Oracle 9i RMAN but we don't know how to make reference to this file.

We have not found any specific reference, documentations explains we need specific parameters from how this bak file was created... but customers says "normal" parameters.

We just installed oracle 9i with default database configuration, we don't want database instead we only want SQL tables and data.

Do you know how to ask for these parameters?
How to specify in RMAN the location of this file?

Any tool to recover data without installind the database?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This does not appear to be a programming related question...

Comment: Is a logfile available from the creation of the backup? Or, are the backup scripts available?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this is an RMAN backup set? Maybe it is just a dump file made while the database is online. For 9i you only had exp and not the newer expdp available to make dumps so you could try to import it with imp and see what the output is:

```
imp system/password@abc FULL=Y FILE=file_decrypted_379299.bak
```

Comment: Not sure it is a RMAN backup. I tried your suggestion and something about "Characters set is undefined". I'm looking further with user. Thanks.